# Перемещение в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Есть такой код:

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.image = cycle_left
        self.rect.x -= self.speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.image = cycle_right
        self.rect.x += self.speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.image = cycle_up
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.image = cycle_down
        self.rect.y += self.speed
    else:
        self.image = cycle_up
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
```

Если нажать и держать стрелку влево (или любую другую), то мотоцикл будет ехать влево до тех пор, пока я не отпущу клавишу. А мне нужно сделать так, чтобы достаточно было один раз нажать на клавишу и мотоцикл ехал влево до тех пор, пока не будет нажата другая клавиша. P.S.: Вторая проблема, если даже зажать клавишу и ехать влево, то картинка дергается между cycle_up и cycle_left

Comment: Нужно реагировать на события нажатия и на события отпускания. Если одна клавиша нажата, а другая раньше была нажата, но не была "отжата" значит они в данный момент нажаты обе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
direction = ""
# используйте строчку выше в начале своего кода(где указываете все переменные)
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or direction == "left":
    self.image = cycle_left
    self.rect.x -= self.speed
    direction = "left"
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or direction == "right":
    self.image = cycle_right
    self.rect.x += self.speed
    direction = "right"
elif keys[pygame.K_UP] or direction == "up":
    self.image = cycle_up
    self.rect.y -= self.speed
    direction = "up"
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or direction == "down":
    self.image = cycle_down
    self.rect.y += self.speed
    direction = "down"
else:
    self.image = cycle_up
    self.rect.y -= self.speed
    direction = "up"
```

По-моему я решил вашу проблему, с помощью добавления переменной направления(direction).